# How can I copy the contents of a Javascript object to an empty one?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have a Javascript object (JSON returned from a database) for use in an Angular site:

```
[{'widget_id':'1','widget_name':'Blue Widget','widget_description':'A nice blue widget','widget_discount':'20'},{'widget_id':'2','widget_name':'Red Widget','widget_description':'A fantastic red widget','widget_discount':'0'}]
```

I want to process this information before I use it in my view - say I want to alter the discount or perform some other operations. Therefore I want to make a new object, iterate through my JSON, and write certain values from the JSON object to the new, blank object.

For now I've just been trying to test copying one value from the old array to a new one, in my Angular controller:

```
WidgetSvc.fetchWidgets().success(function(response){
            var rawWidgets = response
            var widgetsOutput = {}
            for (var i in rawWidgets){
              widgetsOutput[i].widget_id = rawWidgets[i].widget_id
            }
```

But this throws a `cannot set property 'widget_id' of undefined` error. I suspect I'm not initializing the new object properly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There's `angular.copy`, I think you should use that. (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy#!) You're getting that error because `widgetsOutput[anyIndex] = undefined` until you've initialized `widgetsOutput[someIndex]` to some value, preferably an object, since you want to set properties on it.

Comment: While an array *is* an object in JavaScript, we would usually call the structure at top an *array of objects* instead of just an *object*.

Comment: *widgetsOutput[anyIndex] === undefined (Can't edit comments after 5 mins)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just forgot to set you nested object before setting property :

```
var rawWidgets = [{'widget_id':'1','widget_name':'Blue Widget','widget_description':'A nice blue widget','widget_discount':'20'},{'widget_id':'2','widget_name':'Red Widget','widget_description':'A fantastic red widget','widget_discount':'0'}];

var widgetsOutput = {}
for (var i in rawWidgets){
    widgetsOutput[i] = {}
    widgetsOutput[i].widget_id = rawWidgets[i].widget_id
}

console.log(widgetsOutput)
```

Comment: You could also combine the statements like this:  `widgetsOutput[i] = {widget_id: rawWidgets[i].widget_id}`.

Comment: This works, but I've declared `widgetsOutput` as an array (`[]`) rather than an object as this then matches the output from the database. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

JSON != Javascript Object.  You can [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to make your JSON into a proper Javascript object:

```
WidgetSvc.fetchWidgets().success(function(response){
        var data = JSON.parse(response);

        // now you can do
        data[0].widget_discount = 10;
 }
```